# Validate and pass only valid characters against regex expression in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on solution where I need to validate and pass only valid characters of string in c#.
E.g. my regular expression is  : `"^\\S(|(.|\\n)*\\S)\\Z"`
and text I want validate is below

```
127 Finchfield Lane
```

Now I know its invalid. But how do I remove invalid against regex and pass only if string validate successfully against regex ?

Comment: What do you consider 'valid characters'?

Comment: @Mahajan344 do you want to check condition only like if or else? or any other

Comment: @SjorsOttjes If string pass through regex that means its valid..

Comment: @BalajiMarimuthu I want first check whether string characters are valid against regex.. if not then strip those invalid char from string

Comment: It's not at all clear from that pattern what you consider to be valid or invalid characters.

Comment: The real part of your question is *"I need to validate and pass only valid characters of string"* the rest is your ideas on the wrong way to do it as described in [the X-Y question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please show what you have tried, see [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, you are looking for `Regex.IsMatch`

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(str, "^\\S(|(.|\\n)*\\S)\\Z"))
{
    // do something with the valid string
}
else
{
    // strip invalid characters from the string
}
```

Comment: I am also looking for how to strip invalid char

Comment: but how do i stripe.. that my question

Comment: @Mahajan344 It would be a lot easier to answer if you knew what characters you wanted to strip (or which ones you want to keep)

Comment: that main problem.. I only have regex.. which I have to validate against... if it pass that means its valid.. if its not then that means its invalid string.. so I have to remove those invalid...

Comment: @Mahajan344 In that case i can't help. I don't think there is a way to solve this problem if you don't know what valid input is. The regex you have right now matches a very wide range of strings, it doesn't seem like a good idea to use that regex to validate something

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace PatternMatching
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string pattern = @"(\d+) (\w+)";

            string[] strings = { "123 ABC", "ABC 123", "CD 45678", "57998 DAC" };

            foreach (var s in strings)
            {
                Match result = Regex.Match(s, pattern);

                if (result.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Match: {0}", result.Value);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to do what you require. Hope I haven't misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

To validate the string against regex you can use use **Regex.IsMatch**.

```
Regex.IsMatch(string, pattern) //returns true if string is valid
```

If you want to get the Match value only then you can use it.

```
Match match = new Regex(@"\d+").Match(str);
match.value;  //it returns only the matched string and unmatched string automatically stripped out
```

Comment: Its not working  because when I checked Regex.IsMatch("BAYR BALLAGAWNE","^\\S(|(.|\\n)*\\S)\\Z") ,  its returning true.. but  same string pass to above method returns value as blank

Comment: @Mahajan344 use @ symbol infront of pattern. Regex.IsMatch("BAYR BALLAGAWNE",@"^\S(|(.|\n)*\S)\Z")

Comment: @Mahajan344 What is it about that string that makes you think it should return false?

Comment: @BalajiMarimuthu If you do that then you need to remove the double backslashes. Unless of course OP _wants_ to have those backslash literals in the pattern.

Comment: @Mahajan344 your pattern returns the value, hence it returns true.

Comment: but if pattern return true then how come if same pattern and string is passed to Match then Match.Value is blank ?

Comment: @Mahajan344 Because your pattern allows it. Your first group alternative is empty, so that will match on nothing. Literally. As in, it would return a valid result no matter what string you passed it, even an empty string `""`.